# How to compare only values in two different dictionaries which belongs to different keys in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, compare, key-value-store

I have Two dictionaries as Dict and Dict_BM.
There content are as follows:
Dict Content:
Product_ID,1113

Dict 2 content :
Test,1113

I just want to compare the '1113' values from both the dictionaries as 'Test' is the value for 'Product_ID' from other XML which is being captured in Dict_BM.

Code so far is as follows:

```
bool equal = false;
    if (Dict.Count == Dict_BM.Count) 
    {
        equal = true;
        foreach (var pair in Dict)
        {
        int value;
        if (Dict_BM.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out value))
        {
            // Require value be equal.
            if (value != pair.Value)
            {
            equal = false;
            break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Require key be present.
            equal = false;
            break;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Currently, you're assuming the same keys between the two dictionaries - but that doesn't match the example you've given (where the keys are "Product_ID" and "Test"). We'll need the question to be a lot clearer before we can help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet.Thanks. Let me explain it again.Actually i have captured the data from two different xmls for both dictionaries.                         Dic 1 contains (PRODUCT_ID,1113) and Dict_BM contains (Test,1113).Please note that 'Test' is corresponding to the 'PRODUCT_ID' which was present in second xml.I finally want to compare the values for Test and 'PRODUCT_ID' which is being collected in both the dictionaries as '1113'. Please let me know if that explains my question.

Comment: Don't explain it in comments - edit your question. It's not at all clear what you mean by "Test is corresponding to the PRODUCT_ID which was present in the second xml". How is the dictionary meant to "know" that? Currently your comment is basically repeating what's already in the question - it doesn't actually clarify anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. actually the dic 1 is being created using an xml file generated as API response whereas Dict_BM is being generated from xml file which is created using a DB query.

Comment: Again, edit your question rather than just adding comments - but you *still* haven't addressed the fact that your dictionaries have different keys. (I'm assuming that "(PRODUCT_ID, 1113)" is meant to be a single entry with a key of PRODUCT_ID and a value of 1113.)

Comment: @JonSkeet. Yes (PRODUCT_ID, 1113) is present in Dict and (Test,1113) is present in Dict_BM. I want to validate the '1113' values in both the dictionaries.

Comment: I give up, I'm afraid. The code you've suggested requires that the keys are the same, but they're clearly not. You haven't explained how you expect that to ever work. Likewise, there could be completely *different* entries which happen to have the same keys. I'm afraid I'll have to leave it to someone else to help you...

Comment: Please show sample of data with 3 {key,value} pairs for each dictionaries (note that dictionary *does not* preserver order) and show example of comparison you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if dictionaries have the same values (but, mayhaps, the different keys)

```
public static Boolean DictionaryHaveEqualValues(IDictionary left, IDictionary right) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
    return true;
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
    return false;
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(right, null))
    return false;

  if (left.Count != right.Count)
    return false;

  Dictionary<Object, int> reversed = new Dictionary<Object, int>();

  foreach (var value in left.Values)
    if (reversed.ContainsKey(value))
      reversed[value] = reversed[value] + 1;
    else
      reversed.Add(value, 1);

  foreach (var value in right.Values)
    if (!reversed.ContainsKey(value))
      return false;
    else if (reversed[value] == 1)
      reversed.Remove(value);
    else
      reversed[value] = reversed[value] - 1;

  return (reversed.Count == 0);
}

....

Dictionary<int, String> main = new Dictionary<int, String>() {
  {1, "A"},
  {2, "B"},
  {3, "A"}
};

Dictionary<int, String> test1 = new Dictionary<int, String>() {
  {7, "A"},
  {4, "B"},
  {5, "A"}
};

Dictionary<int, String> test2 = new Dictionary<int, String>() {
  {7, "A"},
  {4, "B"},
  {5, "A"},
  {9, "B"}
 };

Dictionary<int, String> test3 = new Dictionary<int, String>() {
  {7, "A"},
  {4, "C"},
  {5, "A"},
};

// Dictionarys have equal values: two "A" and one "B"
Debug.Assert(DictionaryHaveEqualValues(main, test1));

// Unequal: test2 simply has move values
Debug.Assert(!DictionaryHaveEqualValues(main, test2));

// Unequal: test3 doesn't have "B" value
Debug.Assert(!DictionaryHaveEqualValues(main, test3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were trying to compare the values of two dictionaries, right?

probably this does what you want:

```
   var equals = (Dict.Count == Dict_BM.Count) && 
                (!Dict.Values.Except(Dict_BM.Values).Any()) && 
                (!Dict_BM.Values.Except(Dict.Values).Any());
```